# Get real count of solutions of MIP Gurobi model

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I have a MIP model that was already solved to some extent with a time limit, and now I want to get exactly one more solution.

One way to produce one additional solution is to keep doing this from the beginning by incrementing `model.Params.SolutionLimit` one by one.

But in my situation I don't know how many solutions were produced up until now, so how I can I set a reasonable `Params.SolutionLimit` that is exactly one higher than the number of solutions until now?

`model.SolCount` does not help since that is capped by a certain limit (defaulting to 10)

Comment: Wholly impossible to answer without a lot more detail and a reproducible example. We don't know what your model is. There are various approaches to MIP solution counting.

Comment: Could you just set the solutionlimit to one and solve again? Otherwise, you can use a callback function to implement the logic when to stop yourself.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen setting the `SolutionLimit` to one does not work since this is not something that resets after every run (like `TimeLimit` does, for example). So apparently there must be some internal counter that `SolutionLimit` is compared to. Using callbacks is how I solved it now. Also see: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/22443213510545-Get-real-count-of-solutions